# Can I add spacers to my cassette and crank to fit 3" tyres?

Tags: tire, chain, crankset, cassette

Can I add spacers to my cassette and crank to fit 3" tyres? The chain rubs on the tyre.

I’m running a hope hub with SRAM 8 speed cassette and saint cranks. Can I just buy spacers to pull the cranks and cassette out so the chain is away from the tyre?

Comment: I don't think that would work very well.

Comment: How wide were the tyres it came with?  2" ?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

For the cassette: the cassette mounts on the freehub body. The position of the freehub body on is fixed on the hub. Besides, there is no room for the cassette to move outwards as it's inside the frame.

For the cranks: depending in what width bottom bracket shell you have, *perhaps* there *might* be a solution using a crank with a longer axle and a wider bottom bracket **but** you really don't want to do that because you'll end up with a very bad chain line alignment.

I'm actually surprised you have not run into lack of tire space between the chainstays before hitting the chain.